# How to combine OfBiz with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ant, frameworks, open-source, ofbiz

I am a beginner to OfBiz framework.I downloded ant.zip  and apache-ofbiz-09.04.01.zip and unpacked to a directory and I have set path variable Ant_Home also and tried with some command line commands found in the tutorial available in the Internet. I tried a  lot of tutorials to combine the OfBiz and the eclipse but I could not succeed in that.Can anyone say the step by step clear procedure for doing this correctly...Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Ant installation is not necessary to run Ofbiz, since its an inbuilt feature in the framework,

1. First load the project in to eclipse (New -->Java Project -->Select Project location)
2. Build the project (Right click build.xml run as Ant Build)
3. then follow the steps in the link below

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Running+and+Debugging+OFBiz+in+Eclipse#RunningandDebuggingOFBizinEclipse-debuggingInEclipse

Answer (score 0):

just follow this link https://github.com/pashtika/OFBiz

Or

The following are the steps to setup / configure Apache OFBiz 13.07.01 in Eclipse / STS (Spring Tool Suite) are as follows -

```
•   Select OFBiz (or ofbiz-release13.07) project, right-click on it -> Run As -> Run ... (alike for Debug)
•   Select Java Application and click on New
•   Set Run configuration name to OFBiz

o   Main tab:
*************
-   Project: OFBiz
-   Main class: org.ofbiz.base.start.Start
-   If you need it (to trace a framework bug in the 1st loaded class) you may use the "Stop in Main" Option

o   Arguments:
```

---

```
-   VM arguments: -Xms(minValue)M -Xmx(maxValue)M  (typically minValue = 128, maxValue = 512, more is better of course) (Ex: -Xms128M -Xmx512M)

•   In some case (Suse SL 10.1 at least) it's better to not define any VM arguments but let the defaults values.
-   Working directory: Use default working directory

•   Classpath
  o Bootstrap Entries: JRE System Library
  o User Entries: ofbiz.jar from OFBiz project
-   Don't forget to remove the entry "ofbiz (default classpath)" else you may have a message "Can't find bundle for base name cache, locale ..."

•    Source tab
******************
  o Click Add Projects... (buttons on the right)
  o Select the ofbiz project

•   Environment
******************
  o Add environment variable LC_ALL=C (Optional, Linux only)
•   Click on Apply and Run (or Debug)
```

Here is with your final screen you can see:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Flowing Answer appropriate For Ubuntu OS only.........!

**Step 1:** After downloading the jdk file open the terminal **Ctrl + Alt + T** for navigate to the file. *

> *(you can use **sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal** *for open Terminal in Any location*)*

- **tar -xf jdk-7u75-linux-i586.tar.gz**

This will extract and create a jdk folder at your current path.

**Step 2:** Create a location to keep your new JDK . I prefer and usually use /usr/lib/jvm/

You may need root permission to create the /usr/lib/jvm (hence use sudo).

**sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm**

**Step 3:** Move the extracted jdk folder to /usr/lib/jvm/

**sudo mv jdk1.7.0_75 /usr/lib/jvm/**

**Step 4:** Now we have to setup our system to use refer to our new jdk

**sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java" 1 
sudo update-alternatives --config java**

And also register Firefox Java Plugin

**sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so" 
"mozilla-javaplugin.so" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so" 1 
sudo update-alternatives --config mozilla-javaplugin.so**

ALL DONE. You can test your java install by     **java -version**

Then Same way for Apache ant:

**sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/ant" "ant" "/usr/lib/jvm/apache-ant-1.9.2/bin/ant" 1 
sudo update-alternatives --config ant**

You can test your ant install by       **ant -version**

Then Set Path:    For java path setup go to terminal &  type:   **sudo nano /etc/environment**

**JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_75"** 
**ANT_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/apache-ant-1.9.2"** 
**PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_75/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/apache-ant-1.9.2/bin"**

**Step 5:** After installing Apache OFBiz, Use following command to start Apache OFBiz service on system:
Go to The OfBiz Folder Directory & open TERMINAL Then type the following Command:

1. **sudo ant clean-all**
2. **sudo ant load-demo**
3. **sudo ant load-extseed**   // this is not mendotory; it is used for changes of Entity
4. **sudo ant start**              // This will Start Apache OFBiz Service

Step 6: Access Apache OFBiz in Browser

Access Apache OFBiz in browser on port 8443 as below given url and login credentials.

URL:  **https://localhost:8443/humanres/control/main**

Admin Username: **admin**

Admin Password: **ofbiz**

Thats All Done...................!